# Saving to Parse in a while loop swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I have a problem where I call save after putting some items in an object. I go to an API and I download some info and then I save it to another system for temporary use, however the .save() seems to only save 2 items, with no special pattern in which it selects. Can someone explain what the problem is?

```
let url = URL(string: link)
    let spots = PFObject(className:"spot")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else{
            if let urlContent = data{

                do{
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                    let results = (jsonResult as! NSDictionary)["results"]
                    let venueList = (results as! NSArray)
                    //print(jsonResult)
                    var i = 0
                    while i < venueList.count{
                        let venues = venueList[i] as! NSDictionary
                        let name = venues["name"] as! String
                        let geometry = venues["geometry"] as! NSDictionary
                        let location = geometry["location"] as! NSDictionary
                        let cLat = location["lat"] as! Double
                        let cLon = location["lng"] as! Double
                        let vPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: cLat, longitude: cLon)
                        //print(name," ", vPoint)
                        spots["venue"] = name
                        spots["name"] = vPoint
                        do{
                           try HotSpots.save()
                            print("Saved! ",name," ", vPoint)
                        }
                        catch{
                            print("Save Error")
                        }
                        i+=1
                    }




                }
                catch{
                    print("JSON Error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What is `HotSpots`? Side-note: `while i < ...` and incrementing a counter is very bad syntax in Swift. The usual syntax is a `for - in`.

Comment: I'll make sure to fix that! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're saving the two values always in the same `PFObject` instance.

Move the line `let spots = PFObject(className:"spot")` in the loop.

PS: Use Swift native types. For example this is more efficient

```
let location = geometry["location"] as! [String:Double]
let cLat = location["lat"]!
let cLon = location["lng"]!
```

Comment: That did it,  Thank you!